# Trying to concatenate xpath descendant::text items

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from Wikipedia, specifically from the following page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_County_Sheriff%27s_Department

I'm wanting to get the header and data under the Agency Overview vcard on the right, but I'm having trouble with the table data.  Some of the /td items contain sub-elements which are recorded as another item in the python list.

For example, this XPath:

```
self.tree.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr/td/descendant::text()[(preceding::*[contains(text(),"Agency overview")]) and (following::*[contains(text(),"Jurisdictional structure")])  ]')
```

returns:

```
['1850', 'Budgeted items:20,159 (2015)', '[1]', 'US$2,994,887,000', ' (2015)', '[1]', 'Governmental: ', 'Government agency']
```

Since there are four header elements, I need it to return four data elements.  How can I concatenate all of the elements under each /td?

Comment: you can get individual item as follow: //th[text()='Formed']/following-sibling::td[1]

Comment: While I used that page as an example, there are more.  I won't always know how many items are under Agency Overview, so I can't use static numbers.

Comment: I will give you one suggestion as follow.
First Find      : //th[text()='Agency overview']/parent::tr[1]/following-sibling::tr
================
Second Find ://th[text()='Jurisdictional structure']/parent::tr[1]/following-sibling::tr
================

total = len(First Find) - len(Second Find) - 1

I hope this equation helpful

Comment: That really won't work either, as I need all the td data to match up with the row that includes the th.  For example, the 2nd 'th' element, matches up with item 2 + 3 in the list ('Budgeted items:20,159 (2015)', '[1]').  Thanks for the ideas so far though.